# Comments field displays only plain text

Tags: 7, comments

I have a Drupal 7 site where people might want to put code snippets in a comment.  I have the [geshi](https://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) module set up for syntax highlighting.

I have an article node set to the Full HTML text format, and some code snippets.  The article is displayed properly, the code is highlighted.

I have created a comment on the article with the text format also set to Full HTML, and some code snippets.  The comment displays the literal html code, as if the text format is plain text or something.  I have BUEditor and Ajax markup installed, and the preview they give me shows it highlighted.  But Drupal's preview is consistent with the real output.

I've tried googling for this problem, but between most people wanting the opposite and the term `comment` being on pretty much every webpage these days, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the following:

```
    <csharp>line1
    line2
    line3</csharp>
```

Those extra 4 spaces in the beginning made Markdown put that in a `<pre>`, and then geshi still processed the csharp block.  Taking out the spaces in the beginning made it work correctly.